Route error in Rust using Axum and AWS SDK. 'the trait bound `fn(axum::Json<EmailRequest>,'
I am very, very new to Rust. I am trying to get this /send_email endpoint working. If anyone can point my in a good direction on the error I would really appreciate it.
My send-email route in the send_email handler:
pub fn router(client: Arc<Client>) -> Router {
    Router::new()
        .route("/send-email", post(send_email_request))
}

Error:
the trait bound `fn(axum::Json<EmailRequest>, Extension<Arc<aws_sdk_sesv2::Client>>) -> impl std::future::Future<Output = impl IntoResponse> {send_email_request}: Handler<_, _, _>` is not satisfied

The full doc:
use axum::{
    extract::{Extension, Json},
    response::{IntoResponse, Response},
    http::StatusCode,
    routing::post,
    Router,
    Json as AxumJson,
};
use aws_sdk_sesv2::Client;
use std::sync::Arc;
use serde_json::json;
use crate::signage::email_service::{send_email, EmailRequest};
use crate::util::check_payload; // Assuming this function is correctly implemented
use tracing::instrument;

pub fn router(client: Arc<Client>) -> Router {
    Router::new()
        .route("/send-email", post(send_email_request))
}

#[instrument]
#[utoipa::path(
    post,
    path = "/api/v1/send_email",
    responses(
        (status = 200, description = "Email sent successfully", body = String),
        (status = 500, description = "Failed to send email")
    )
)]
pub async fn send_email_request(
    Json(payload): Json<EmailRequest>,
    Extension(client): Extension<Arc<Client>>
) -> impl IntoResponse {
    let payload = match check_payload(&payload) {
        Ok(valid_payload) => valid_payload,
        Err(error) => return (StatusCode::BAD_REQUEST, AxumJson(json!({"error": error.to_string()}))).into_response(),
    };

    match send_email(&client).await {
        Ok(_) => {
            (StatusCode::OK, AxumJson(json!({"message": "Email sent successfully."}))).into_response()
        },
        Err(e) => {
            (StatusCode::INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR, AxumJson(json!({"error": format!("Failed to send email: {}", e)}))).into_response()
        }
    }
}


try using debug_handler on the function. It will create a better error message. It also seems the client is unused in router

There were a few other issues. The main one ended up being something simple. It was an order problem in send_email_request. The Extension needed to come before payload. So now, its
Extension(client): Extension<Arc<Client>>,
payload: Option<Json<EmailRequest>> 


It would help to outline the other issues as well, since you did post code that other novices may try to use
